# Iterando registros en una ruta anidada - Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Tengo registros en el cual deseaba que se mostrar con esta url: `http://localhost:3000/surveys/1/respondents/1` lo cual he conseguido mediante:

```
resources :surveys do
  resources :respondents
end
```

Y para mostrar el formulario lo hago mediante: `<%= form_for([@survey, @respondent]) do |form| %>` y todo indica estar bien, mi problema viene a la hora de poder iterar los respondents que pertenecen al id del survey actual

```
<% @respondents.each do |respondent| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= respondent.name %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', [ @survey, respondent ] %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_respondent_path(respondent) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', respondent, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Pues en el caso del enlace a la vista show: `<%= link_to 'Show', respondent %>` la variable `respondent` no funcionaba por lo que lo modifique de esta forma: `<%= link_to 'Show', [ @survey, respondent ] %>` pero tampoco puedo hacerlo funcionar, supongo tiene que ver la forma en como tengo estructuado el loop, agradezco puedan ayudarme

**respondents_controller.rb**

```
class RespondentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_respondent, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /respondents
  # GET /respondents.json
  def index
    @respondents = Respondent.all
  end

  # GET /respondents/1
  # GET /respondents/1.json
  def show

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.pdf { render template: 'respondents/report', pdf: 'Report' }
    end

  end

  # GET /respondents/new
  def new
    @survey = Survey.find(params[:survey])
    @respondent = Respondent.new
    @respondent.answers.build
    @answer_option = @respondent.answer_options.build
    @answer_option.sub_answer_options.build
  end

  # GET /respondents/1/edit
  def edit
    @respondent.answers.build
  end

  # POST /respondents
  # POST /respondents.json
  def create
    @respondent = Respondent.new(respondent_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @respondent.save
        format.html { redirect_to survey_respondent_path(@survey, @respondent), notice: 'Respondent was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @respondent }
        ResultMailer.respondent(@respondent).deliver_later
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @respondent.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /respondents/1
  # PATCH/PUT /respondents/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @respondent.update(respondent_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @respondent, notice: 'Respondent was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @respondent }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @respondent.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /respondents/1
  # DELETE /respondents/1.json
  def destroy
    @respondent.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to respondents_url, notice: 'Respondent was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_respondent
      @respondent = Respondent.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def respondent_params
      params.require(:respondent).permit(:name, :email, :phone, :survey_id, answers_attributes: [:id, :response, :question_id,  :respondent_id], answer_options_attributes: [:id, :response, :question_id, :respondent_id, sub_answer_options_attributes: [:id, :answer_option_id, response: [] ]])
    end
end
```

**index.html.erb**

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<h1>Respondents</h1>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>Phone</th>
      <th>Survey</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @respondents.each do |respondent| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= respondent.name %></td>
        <td><%= respondent.email %></td>
        <td><%= respondent.phone %></td>
        <td><%= respondent.survey.id %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', [ @survey, respondent ] %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_respondent_path(respondent) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', respondent, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br>

<%= link_to 'New Respondent', new_respondent_path %>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Puedes compartir el código completo de la vista y la acción del controlador relacionada? Así podremos ver exactamente como están definidos `@respondents` y `@survey`.

Comment: ¿Cuál es el error? ¿Qué muestran los logs?

Comment: Acabo de actualizar el Post @Gerry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En `link_to` debes especificar el `id` del `Survey` al que pertenece el `Respondent`, sin embargo en tu vista pasas el objeto `@survey` que no está definido en la acción `index` y, por lo tanto, no tienes `survey` relacionado.

Para que funcione el código, simplemente cambia `@survey` por `respondent.survey`:

```
<%= link_to 'Show', [ respondent.survey, respondent ] %>
```

Para que funcione debes confirmar que tus relación `belongs_to` entre los modelos `Respondent` y `Survey` sea la correcta, i.e.:

```
class Respondent < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :survey

  #...
end
```

Comment: Excelente @Gerry, y en el caso del edit Gerry intente algo como esto pero no funciono: `<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_survey_respondent_path([ respondent.survey, respondent ]) %>`

Comment: @HectorHernandez Debe ser `@respondent` y sin corchetes: `edit_survey_respondent_path(@respondent.survey, @respondent)`.

Comment: Excelente Gerry, dentro del link de destroy lo actualice de esta manera: `<%= link_to 'Destroy', [ respondent.survey, respondent ], method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>`  Lo cual no da ningun problema, pero si le doy clic para eliminar, obtengo un error, acabo de agregar una imagen al final del post para que veas q error me da al ahora de eliminar @Gerry

Comment: @HectorHernandez El error se debe a que el registro que quieres borrar está referenciado en la tabla `answers`, por lo tanto no se puede borrar. Si tienes dudas de como hacerlo te pido abras una nueva pregunta, para no mezclar temas y dejar 1 problema por pregunta. Mientras tanto, si esta respuesta ayudó a resolver el problema original, no olvides aceptarla (dando clic a la paloma).

Comment: Claro @Gerry, creo que se solucinaria con un dependent: :destroy, lo intentare en caso contrario te notifico, te agradezco por echarme esta mano! =D